# What is the maven dependency for db2java and db2jcc

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, db2, pom.xml

How to download maven dependency for db2java and db2jcc?
getting below error in maven project

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

Answer (score 1):

Although free, DB2 drivers are a commercial product, and there are no official maven repositories for them. You must download the drivers from the [official site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866), and add them to your project yourself. What you want is most likely *IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ* and the associated jar files.